# Is there a way to use WebSockets on IBM WebSphere Application Server?

Tags: java, websocket, websphere-7

I am migrating a web application based on Apache Tomcat 7.0.35 using the WebSocket Servlets to IBM WebSphere Application Server (WAS). The problem is that I don't think WAS supports WebSockets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WAS doesn't support WebSockets as stated on an IBM forum [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=14865076). What you can do is to investigate if you can deploy in WAS one of the WebSockets server implementations (check this [list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_WebSocket_implementations)).

Answer (score 6):

You can try the WebSphere Liberty 8.5.5.4 -- this supports WebSockets. See announcement [here](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/blog/2014/12/09/announcing-new-liberty-features-tools/).

See also:

- [Liberty profile: Web Sockets](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/cwlp_websockets.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can also try embedding the Jetty Web Server on the java application to run on your WebSphere Application Server - http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/embedding-jetty.html. Another option is to make use of a WebSockets implementation (e.g. Wabbit), or make use of an Application Server that supports the Java EE 7 specs, like IBM WAS 9.